# Hiding header on content scrolling in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

ion-header is fixed, it stays at the top of the screen at all times.

I would like it to disappear with the page as you scroll.

Ive put it into ion-content which works but it has unintended side effects. Does anyone know how to create ion-header so that its not fixed to the top at all time and moved with the page ?

Comment: for this kind of question use the google first
https://medium.com/@gregor.srdic/ionic3-hidding-header-on-footer-on-content-scroll-15ab95b05dc5

Comment: I thought there must be a way to do this with Ionic itself. This seems a bit involved. Also this code doesn’t work for Ionic 4

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
<ion-header *ngIf="hide">
```

While you capture the event and do

```
this.hide = !this.hide;
```

Tested with a button click event, and works :)

Same can be changed using Simple CSS Class, but it's up to you as per your requirements.

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

in the onScroll function code behind you can toggle the "hide"

```
onScroll(event:any) { 
    console.log(event); 
    this.hide = !this.hide; 
}
```

variable to show/hide the header.

Also, the following [ionic-4-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events/) may be helpful for you as to how to scroll the content.

Comment: He need not to hide forever , only after scrolling some height

Comment: Well you will have to track as per your scroll events for example :
`<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">`
The hide is not permanent, you can always set it to true or false or true as per your requirement.